# Convert date string to timestamp, groovy

Tags: groovy, timestamp

I have a date string as follows:

```
201805041235040000000
```

Which I would like to convert to timestamp with zone in Groovy.
Tried this:

```
def timestamp = Date.parse("yyyyMMddHHmmss", timstamp).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

But failed, got error:

```
No signature of method: static java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types.
```

Let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: it looks like a timestamp  "yyyyMMddhhmmss, mmmuuun"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works...

```
String input = '201805041235040000000'

String timestamp = Date.parse('yyyyMMddHHmmss', input).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

Comment: It is difficult to tell from the question what you are really looking for, but that code works and I think may be consistent with what you are asking how to do.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    String t2,st = "16/08/2007 09:04:34"
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    Date date = sdf.parse(st)
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime())
    t2 = timestamp.toString()
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit unclear what you are looking for. If you just need a time stamp from parsing your date string, you can use the groovy extension [Date.toTimestamp()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#toTimestamp()):

```
def ts = Date.parse("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS", "201805041235040000000".take(17)).toTimestamp()
```

where the `take(17)` is there to discard any trailing zeros not included in the date pattern `yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS`. I made the assumption that three of the tailing zeros were milliseconds. If that's not the case:

```
def ts = Date.parse("yyyyMMddHHmmss", "201805041235040000000".take(14)).toTimestamp()
```

what is unclear is what you mean when you say "with zone". So assuming you just want to include the current time zone information and generate a String, I don't see a reason why you should convert from date to timestamp in the first place ([Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) after all is a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) as it inherits from Date). If you just need the timezone spelled out you can do:

```
def withZone = Date.parse("yyyyMMddHHmmss", "201805041235040000000".take(14)).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
println withZone
```

which on my machine where I'm sitting in Sweden prints out:

```
~> groovy withTimeZone.groovy 
2018-05-04T12:35:04+0200
```

Comment: This usage of Date.parse() has been deprecated according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html but instead you can use `new SimpleDateFormat(<format string>).parse(<input string>)`

Answer (score 0):

timestamp must be string. Try this:

```
Date.parse("yyyyMMddHHmmss", timstamp?.toString()[0..13])
    .format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```